# Convert template html in django to pdf and download it

Tags: python, html, css, django, button

How I can create a button on my web page using Django to convert the page to PDF and download it ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this.

...This document explains how to output PDF files dynamically using Django views. This is made possible by the excellent, open-source ReportLab Python PDF library.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/outputting-pdf/

https://www.reportlab.com/dev/install/open_source_installation/